# listview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.1

I am using the listview with C# in VS.NET 2003. I would like to select a single cell (not just cells in the first column). I want to have a cell free selection and it highlight the selection in the cell as well.

Comment: Are you trying to highlight a cell at runtime(IE click) or during binding

Answer (score 3):

For free selection, I expect (in 1.1) [`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(VS.71).aspx) is your best option. In 2.0, this is largely replaced with `DataGridView`, which is much more versatile.

I would also recommend that you consider moving to a more up to data framework version; I realise this isn't always possible, but you will be hamstrung with 1.1.